# When upload site logo, shows Undefined array key warning

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, localhost

I am self learner, and am building website in WordPress. I have no knowledge of php. While I am updating site logo, It shows an error " **'Warning: Undefined array key "options" in C:\xampp\htdocs\basicdesigns\wp-content\plugins\elementor-pro\modules\theme-builder\widgets\site-logo.php on line 194'** " top of the header in browser.

php code is -

```
private function get_caption_source_options() {
        $caption_source_options = $this->get_controls( 'caption_source' )['options'];

        unset( $caption_source_options['custom'] );

        return $caption_source_options;
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: If you had provided some code to look at, we might have been able to help. Given that you didn't, please read the duplicate to get some ideas how to solve this.